# Putting this custom caret in right place

Tags: css

I was searching for custom caret and i found it in this address:

http://lugolabs.com/caret

```
    .caret {
  position: relative;
}

.caret:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  border-top: 10px solid #090909;
  border-left: 10px solid transparent;
  border-right: 10px solid transparent;
}

.caret:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 10px;
  top: 0;
  border-top: 0px solid #eeeeee;
  border-left: 0px solid transparent;
  border-right: 0px solid transparent;
}
```

My quetion is this that how can i put this caret beside the word of "health" in code below:

```
<li class="health"><a href="health/health.php" >health</a></li>
```

Comment: are you want to put a caret before this li ? why you don't use the fontawesome, you can simply add <i class="fa fa-caret-down></i> before the <a>> inside the <li>

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you need to include the `.caret` element wherever you want the caret to be shown. Then, you need to adjust its positioning with other elements as per your needs. Below is an example, but you can use it any way you want by modifying the css rules:

```css
.caret {
  position: relative;
}

.caret:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 3px;
  left: -25px;
  border-top: 10px solid #090909;
  border-left: 10px solid transparent;
  border-right: 10px solid transparent;
}

.caret:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 10px;
  top: 0;
  border-top: 0px solid #eeeeee;
  border-left: 0px solid transparent;
  border-right: 0px solid transparent;
}

ul
{
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="health">
    <i class="caret"></i>
     <a href="health/health.php" >health</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: No, it doesn't work,i have several <li></li> and this caret as your codes goes to another <li></li> and not beside but above that <li></li>.

Answer (score 1):

1- you can just use the fontawesome, and simply you put the code like this

```
 <li><a kref="#"><i class="fa fa-caret-down></i> link</a></li>
```

2- and if you want use the css only,

this code will work for you

```css
ul{
  list-style-type: none;
}
ul li a{
  text-decoration:none;
  color: #00f;
}

ul li.caret-down a{
 color: #f60;
}

ul li.caret-down a::before{
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 99;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  margin-left: -15px;
  margin-top: 6px;
  border-right: 6px solid transparent;
  border-left: 6px solid transparent;
  border-top: 6px solid #f60;
  content: '';
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
  <li class="caret-down"><a href="#">Link 3 - with caret</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
</ul>
```

3 - if you want a picture

```css
ul{
  list-style-type: none;
}
ul li a{
  text-decoration:none;
  color: #00f;
}

ul li.picture a{
 color: #f60;
}

ul li.picture a::before{
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 99;
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  margin-left: -15px;
  margin-top: 3px;
  background-image: url('https://placehold.it/12x12/ff6600/ffffff/?text=x'); /*replace it by your picture*/
  background-size: cover;
  content:'';
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
  <li class="picture"><a href="#">Link 3 - with picture</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: ,is it also possible that i put an small image like a caret beside the word of "health" in my code:<li class="health"><a href="health/health.php" >health</a></li>

Comment: @Kaveh; that is the solution for a picture, in the answer above

Comment: ;thanks and sorry for my delay, i have tested but picture doesn't appear, have you test it?

Comment: @Kaveh; in the demo above; it's a picture

Comment: Thanks a lot,yes it was my mistake.